# how to make user comeback after exipre in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, wampserver

I have executed a statement in phpmyadmin of wamp server

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' password expire
```

Now my password is expired and the page is returned to login panel where I can't put the password. So I can't login.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: @skv i can't write the statement as i can't login

Comment: That has to be run from mysql command prompt, if its local you can do it easily, but if its shared hosting you need to do it in ssh

Comment: @skv, i am stuck in the phpmyadmin login panel, how can i get into command prompt

Comment: is it windows or linux, is it local or remote server?

Comment: it is windows and localhost

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36453/discussion-between-skv-and-bhawin)

Comment: i m sorry my internet connection is slow, the chat page is not opening

Comment: Thats fine, just go to command prompt in windows and start mysql is there any difficulty doing that

Comment: see, i use wamp server with phpmyadmin for mysql, to start it you should have password which was empty earlier , then i made a query to expire password (my mind sucked there) , now the phpmyadmin login page appears which does not accept empty field as password

Comment: but your wamp server has also installed mysql, if you are able to interact with it directly then you can follow the instructions in that page to ensure you reset the password.  The instructions in that page are really detailed, either follow that or understand how it works and do it in any other way...

Comment: please join the chat, it opened